# Geoapify Attribution is required message for commercial use

Tags: node.js, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

1. I am going to use Geoapify Reverse Geocode API in the node.js project. In their site they mentioned Geoapify Attribution is required. Is this mandatory for API project ?

> Can I use the Free plan in commercial projects?
> Yes, we do not restrict that. However, you must provide an appropriate Geoapify attribution or link to our website. The attribution is added automatically to a map if you use style.json to initialize the map. Otherwise, the correct attribution is " Powered by [Geoapify](https://www.geoapify.com/)"

2. Is there any alternative solution to get the country code  while passing lattitute and longtitue in npm packages ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Open Street Map API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim)

It supports shows map and reverse geolocation.

Example reverse geo API

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=48.85341&lon=2.3488
```

[image]

I made a demo program.
It shows a map and reverse geo data by node.js

##### Local Server using express

```js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/map', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


app.get('/reverse', async (req, res) => {
    const lat = req.query.lat;
    const lon = req.query.lon;

    if (!lat || !lon) {
        return res.status(400).send('Latitude and longitude are required');
    }

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse`, {
            params: {
                format: 'json',
                lat: lat,
                lon: lon
            }
        });
        res.json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send('Error occurred while fetching data');
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

##### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map and Data Display</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <style>
        #mapid, #data {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            height: 1024px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapid"></div>
    <div id="data"><pre id="jsonData"></pre></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Function to get URL parameters
        function getURLParameter(name) {
            var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            return params.get(name);
        }

        // Get latitude and longitude from URL parameters
        var lat = getURLParameter('lat') || 48.85341; // Default latitude
        var lon = getURLParameter('lon') || 2.3488;   // Default longitude

        // Initialize map with dynamic latitude and longitude
        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([lat, lon], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
        }).addTo(mymap);
        L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(mymap);

        // Fetch and display data using dynamic latitude and longitude
        axios.get('/reverse', { params: { lat: lat, lon: lon } })
            .then(response => {
                document.getElementById('jsonData').textContent = JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                document.getElementById('jsonData').textContent = "Error: " + error.message;
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Access URL with latitude and longitude input parameters

```
http://localhost:3000/map/?lat=48.85341&lon=2.3488
```

Result

[image]

It is mimic of Geoapify server.

[image]

Comment: same question here. https://osmfoundation.org/wiki/Licence/Attribution_Guidelines. can i use this in api project. IS there any attribution restriction ?

Comment: Open Street Map is Open Database License (ODbL) a license agreement for the free access and use of database content. It is designed to allow users to freely share, modify, and use a database, while also maintaining the same freedom for others. But The 'limited attribution requirement' in ODbL means that any public use of the database, or works produced from the database, must credit the source. In other words, You must acknowledge the source of the data. However, ODbL is designed to be reasonable in its attribution requirements, not demanding overly burdensome or impractical attributions.